# Where did _set came from in tutorial 3 of Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Where did _set came from in the code

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %} in tutorial 3
```

There is choice_set in either Choice or Question model?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Choice` model has a foreign key to the `Question`, so each `question` has `choice_set` to get the related choices.

It's introduced in the [playing with the API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) section in Tutorial 2, and there's a link to the docs on [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/) for more information.